# Real-time text detection in android using opencv

Tags: android, opencv

I have created an android application which detect text regions in real time using OpenCV's MSER algorthim, and its working fine and do what it should do. However when i run it after less than minute the application will close by itself! There are no errors or anything wrong, and its not crashing or shutting down, it will only close the application and return me to my phone's home page. Also there is nothing in the logcat.

Can someone please help with this and tell me where is the problem?

Here's the code of the detect text method:

```
    private void detectText() {
    Scalar CONTOUR_COLOR = new Scalar(255);
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoint = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    List<KeyPoint> listpoint;
    KeyPoint kpoint;
    Mat mask = Mat.zeros(mGrey.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    int rectanx1;
    int rectany1;
    int rectanx2;
    int rectany2;
    int imgsize = mGrey.height() * mGrey.width();
    Scalar zeos = new Scalar(0, 0, 0);

    List<MatOfPoint> contour2 = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    Mat kernel = new Mat(1, 50, CvType.CV_8UC1, Scalar.all(255));
    Mat morbyte = new Mat();
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

    Rect rectan3;
    //
    FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector
            .create(FeatureDetector.MSER);
    detector.detect(mGrey, keypoint);
    listpoint = keypoint.toList();
    //
    for (int ind = 0; ind < listpoint.size(); ind++) {
        kpoint = listpoint.get(ind);
        rectanx1 = (int) (kpoint.pt.x - 0.5 * kpoint.size);
        rectany1 = (int) (kpoint.pt.y - 0.5 * kpoint.size);
        rectanx2 = (int) (kpoint.size);
        rectany2 = (int) (kpoint.size);
        if (rectanx1 <= 0)
            rectanx1 = 1;
        if (rectany1 <= 0)
            rectany1 = 1;
        if ((rectanx1 + rectanx2) > mGrey.width())
            rectanx2 = mGrey.width() - rectanx1;
        if ((rectany1 + rectany2) > mGrey.height())
            rectany2 = mGrey.height() - rectany1;
        Rect rectant = new Rect(rectanx1, rectany1, rectanx2, rectany2);
        try {
            Mat roi = new Mat(mask, rectant);
            roi.setTo(CONTOUR_COLOR);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("mylog", "mat roi error " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    Imgproc.morphologyEx(mask, morbyte, Imgproc.MORPH_DILATE, kernel);
    Imgproc.findContours(morbyte, contour2, hierarchy,
            Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    for (int ind = 0; ind < contour2.size(); ind++) {
        rectan3 = Imgproc.boundingRect(contour2.get(ind));
        rectan3 = Imgproc.boundingRect(contour2.get(ind));
        if (rectan3.area() > 0.5 * imgsize || rectan3.area() < 100
                || rectan3.width / rectan3.height < 2) {
            Mat roi = new Mat(morbyte, rectan3);
            roi.setTo(zeos);

        } else
            Imgproc.rectangle(mRgba, rectan3.br(), rectan3.tl(),
                    CONTOUR_COLOR);
    }
}
```

I profiled the device's memory and it was actually increasing as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

part of the logcat:

```
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper:   Video I/O:
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper:   Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 4.4 interface 9003)
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper:   Other third-party libraries:
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper:     Use IPP:                     NO
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper:     Use Eigen:                   NO
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper:     Use Cuda:                    NO
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper:     Use OpenCL:                  NO
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper:     Use OpenVX:                  NO
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper:     Use custom HAL:              YES (carotene (ver 0.0.1))
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper:   Python 2:
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper:     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.6)
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper:   Python 3:
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper:     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3.4 (ver 3.4.3)
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper:   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper:   Java:
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper:     ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.9.3)
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper:     Java wrappers:               YES
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper:     Java tests:                  NO
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper:   Matlab:                        NO
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper:   Tests and samples:
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper:     Tests:                       NO
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper:     Performance tests:           NO
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper:     C/C++ Examples:              NO
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper:   Install path:                  /build/master_pack-android/build/o4a/install
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper:   cvconfig.h is in:              /build/master_pack-android/build/o4a
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper: -----------------------------------------------------------------
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication D/OpenCVManager/Helper: Init finished with status 0
04-10 15:38:23.183 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication D/OpenCVManager/Helper: Unbind from service
04-10 15:38:23.203 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication D/OpenCVManager/Helper: Calling using callback
04-10 15:38:23.203 31168-31168/com.example.lama.myapplication D/CameraBridge: call checkCurrentState
04-10 15:38:50.803 31168-31178/com.example.lama.myapplication I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 97281(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 14(872KB) LOS objects, 16% free, 18MB/22MB, paused 661us total 106.786ms
04-10 15:38:50.813 31168-31178/com.example.lama.myapplication W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.350ms
04-10 15:39:00.943 31168-31174/com.example.lama.myapplication W/art: Suspending all threads took: 17.194ms
04-10 15:39:04.953 31168-31174/com.example.lama.myapplication W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.868ms
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: If your application is running fine for some and crashing unexpectedly, Then  I suspect `OOM` issue, Out Of Memory. Or there may be some crash in Native as well. Generally native Crashes leave no Traceback as well. I would recommend you to Profile the Memory of your android device to see if it is increasing only, then probably you have a memory leak on Java side.

Comment: @ZdaR how can i check the memory?

Comment: @ZdaR i profiled my device's memory and it was increasing just as you said. I updated my question with a screenshot of the memory. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Did the app crashed automatically at the time of taking screenshot ? because from the screen shot it seems that you still have 4.0 MB free left on the device

Comment: @ZdaR yes it was taken when it was crashed. I'm also wondering what is the problem when there is some memory left, i ran it multiple times to make sure and every time there is some memory left but it crashes. what do you think the problem is?

Comment: Well you could try releasing memory by calling `.release()` on `Mat` objects etc. to release the objects which are not required

Comment: @ZdaR where shall i release them exactly?

Comment: @ZdaR i mean can i release them at the end of the method? or there is specific method to releases them?

Comment: @ZdaR i just uploaded part of the logcat, maybe there is something that i didn't notice.

Comment: You may release in the same method, once the job of that object is done;

Comment: @ZdaR still didn't solve the problem :(

Comment: @ZdaR Don't you have any other solutions?

Comment: Nopes sorry .. :(

Comment: @ZdaR :( that's okay. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @Lama do you got solution? Please add